# Target div using URL's href value

Tags: jquery

I have a simple site where each "page" is actually a `section`. The sections are layered on top of each other using `position:absolute` and `z-index`; when a navigation item is clicked, the section with an id matching the class name of the navigation item is promoted to the top of the stack, changing the "page".

What's got me stuck now, though, is figuring out how to target a particular section from a link within the content of another section. I know the gist of what I have to do, but I'm lost as far as the execution goes.

How I imagine it needs to go is this:

```
$('section a[href^=#]').click(function(){
                var target = $(this).attr(href).(strip the hashtag from the beginning of the link and output the resulting value);
$('body').find('section[id='+target+']').addClass('active').css('z-index', '2')
$('body').find('section[id!='+target+']').removeClass('active').css('z-index', '1')
                });
```

I imagine this involves RegEx somehow, which I know nothing about. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for regexen: the underlying DOM object for links exposes the [Location interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Location_object), which gives you direct access to the parts of the URL as definitively parsed by the browser itself. The `hash` property holds the anchor part including leading `#`, so slice that one character off:

```
this.hash.slice(1);
```

Or even, since you can reuse the `#` for an ID selector:

```
$(this.hash).addClass...
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't know you could extract data from `this` the way you did in your second example. I'm still pretty new to Jquery, so I'm puzzling all this out as I go along.

Comment: @art: indeed, this isn't a jQuery feature, it's part of the underlying browser DOM. There are some things that the Plain Old DOM does that jQuery doesn't really help you with, so it's good to know both.

Answer (score 0):

no need for regex simple split can handle it

```
var id = "";
var ar = $(this).attr('href').toString().split('#');
if(ar.length>0)
   id = ar[1];
if(id.length > 0)
```

//your logic here and don't forget to return false in your logic, otherwise it will continue with the execution

`$(this)` is clicked link

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with bobince's solution since it was a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit easier than the other answer, assuming your hrefs all look like `#section_id`
`var target = $(this).attr(href).substring(1);`

Actually here is another solution. Since the `#` is the jquery id selector, you don't even need to to do any processing on the string. You can do this also

```
var section_id = $(this).attr('href');
$('.section').removeClass('active').css('z-index', '1'); //set all sections to z-index 1
$(section_id).addClass('active').css('z-index', '2'); //set the section you want to z-index 2
```

Comment: This works! I didn't even think about the fact that I'd need the hash sign anyway in order to target the section I wanted. I ended up using bobince's method, though, since it removes my need to declare a variable.

Comment: yeah, that solution is much more elegant.